# Performing a variable number of array dot products in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dot

I'm looking for a quick way to dot and array with itself a variable number of times.

In Mathlab it would look like:

A = some array elements

A^d where d is some scalar.

Hence A^2 is = A*A

However in Python i'm having trouble finding something that does the same thing

A @ A would works when you know have many times your dotting the arrays.

Is there something I missed and could use?

Comment: A while loop, perhaps? You can choose to end it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ["matrix power"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html), and it is computed by [`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html).